# Slow HTTP POST vulnerability in IIS 10

Tags: vulnerability, ddos, iis

I ran a Qualys scan on my website and got a Slow HTTP POST vulnerability. In particular, server resets timeout after accepting request data from peer.

From what I understood from this finding, whenever a similar client restarts its connection to the server, the timer is reset. I have so far configured the **connectionTimeout**, **headerWaitTimeout** and **minBytesPerSecond** in Application Host config **maxAllowedContentLength**  and **maxURL** in web.config. How or what else do I need to configure in IIS to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that http.sys processes all requests for RFC compliance before passing them to IIS. Thus any IIS Request Filtering setting is meaningless. Even `maxContentLength=1` will do nothing if one were to upload a large amount of data. Http.sys will continue to accept the stream. This was identified on a similar thread here (Spoiler alert! http.sys does!):

> [Does IIS Request Content Filtering Load the full request before filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126110/does-iis-request-content-filtering-load-the-full-request-before-filter/59217102#59217102)

### Default Limits for Web Sites

Tune your [website limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) in particular `connectionTimeout`. This will drop long-lived connections and large data uploads. Note that these settings are for the entire site so other pages or services allowing file uploads should be considered when establishing these values. Take the maximum amount of data one should upload along with the lowest allowed speed. However long it takes to transfer that amount of data at that speed is your `connectionTimeout` value.

### Request Filtering

While Request Filtering won't directly address your question, it greatly improves security and may also improve website performance. This is because the module runs very early in the pipeline discarding bad requests before they can get to the slower application layer logic. I wrote a PowerShell module [IISRFBaseline](https://github.com/phbits/IISRFBaseline) which aims to take much of the guess work out of establishing these values by analyzing the IIS logs and website content directory. There's also plenty of README.md to answer any setting specific questions.

### Qualys Recommended Remediation

Qualys offers great tips for addressing this finding though I believe there's too much emphasis on Request Filtering for the reasons mentioned above. That said, here's their recommendation:

> - Limit request attributes is through the <[RequestLimits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)> element, specifically the maxAllowedContentLength, maxQueryString, and maxUrl attributes.
> - Set <[headerLimits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/headerLimits)> to configure the type and size of header your web server will accept.
> - Tune the connectionTimeout, headerWaitTimeout, and minBytesPerSecond attributes of the <[limits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/limits)> and <[WebLimits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/webLimits)> elements to minimize the impact of slow HTTP attacks.
>
> Source: [How to Protect Against Slow HTTP Attacks](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks)